# I wanted to create a java Object by reading a text file

Tags: java, oop

The text file contains the following data :

```
Rock
12
10
0
```

I want to use this data and add as properties to the Object.
The Object Name is the player and the properties are:

- name
- maximum_health
- current_health
- no_of_wins

So when the object is created the player.name is `"Rock"`, player.maximum_health is `12`, player.current_health is `10` and player.no_of_wins is `0`.

Comment: Okay... Do you have a question regarding this information?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) center, take [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn the basics and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Do some research,search for related topics on SO; 
if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Regex named group to get them or use split by space

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    String text = "Rock 12 10 0";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9]+) ([0-9]+) ([0-9]+) ([0-9]+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String name = matcher.group(1);
        String maximum_health = matcher.group(2);
        String current_health = matcher.group(3);
        String no_of_wins = matcher.group(4);
        Player player = new Player(name, maximum_health, current_health, no_of_wins);
    }
}
```

Comment: here how can i convert the maximum health and current health property to double data type and no of wins to integer

Comment: You can use Double.parseDouble(maximum_health); to convert to double and Integer.parseInt(......) to convert from string to int

Comment: If you are sure max and current health are doubles use this pattern `([a-zA-Z0-9]+) ([0-9]+[.]?[0-9]+) ([0-9]+[.]?[0-9]+) ([0-9]+)`